# Usage of PHP Soap

Tags: php, authentication, soap, token, soap-client

I'm triying to insert data a remote server via SOAP. But got the error below:

*object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["DataInsertResult"]=> string(51) "Hata : DI - Value cannot be null. Parameter name: s" }*

Here you can find tehe my code below:

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient("http://www.posta-tr.com/MassDataAccepter/MassDataAccepter.asmx?wsdl");
$connect = $client->Authenticate("accountname", "password");

$send = $client->DataInsert(array(
"idRoot" => array (
    "DataToDb" => array(
        "Drow" => array (
            "FName" => "George",
            "LName" => "Houston",
            "Email" => "gerorge@emailprovider.com",
            "InvitedBy" => "Mary J",
            "Job" => "Architect",
            "City" => "Newyork",
        )
    ) 
)

));
var_dump($send);
echo $client->DataInsertResponse;
?>
```

How I can solve this problem?

Hi,Here you can see the .net (?) code of my webservice provider. How can i use this as php code?

```
Webservice Url: http://www.posta-tr.com/MassDataAccepter/MassDataAccepter.asmx?wsdl

protected void btn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PwebS.MassDataAccepter mda = new PwebS.MassDataAccepter();
        string Result = "Error!";
        string Token = mda.Authenticate("user", "pass");
        string data = @"<idRoot>
<DataToDb>
<Drow>
<FName>George</FName>
<LName>Houston</LName>
<Email>gerorge@emailprovider.com</Email>
<InvitedBy>Mary J</InvitedBy>
<Job>Architect</Job>
<City>Newyork</City>
</Drow>
</DataToDb>
</idRoot>";

        if (Token.Length > 30)
        {
            Result = mda.DataInsert(Token, data);
        }
        if (Result.Contains("Inserted : 1"))
            lbl_Info.Text = "Data Inserted!";
        else if (Result.Contains("Updated : 1"))
            lbl_Info.Text = "There is same data in db! Duplicate Data!";
        else
            lbl_Info.Text = "Error!";
    }
```

Hi, after a few days i got an interesting news... php_soap can not connect the webservice but nusoap works fine! Below you can see my code but i got a new error you can see the error after the code :)

```
<?PHP
require_once('includes/nusoap/nusoap.php');
$client = new nusoap_client("http://www.posta-tr.com/MassDataAccepter/MassDataAccepter.asmx?wsdl", "wsdl","", "", "", "");
$err = $client->getError();
if ($err) {
echo "<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>" . $err . "</pre>";
}
$params = array(
    'Username'=>'my_username',
    'Password'=>'my_password'
);
$result = $client->call("Authenticate", $params, "", "", false, true);

if ($client->fault) {
echo "<h2>Fault</h2><pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
} else {
// Check for errors
$err = $client->getError();
if ($err) {
// Display the error
echo "<h2>Error</h2><pre>" . $err . "</pre>";
} else {
// Display the result
echo "<h2>Result</h2><pre>";
print_r($result);
$tokenkey = $result['AuthenticateResult'];
echo $tokenkey;
echo "</pre>";
}
}
$veri = "<idRoot>
    <DataToDb>
    <Drow>
    <FName>George</FName>
    <LName>Houston</LName>
    <Email>gerorge@emailprovider.com</Email>
    <InvitedBy>Mary J</InvitedBy>
    <Job>Architect</Job>
    <City>Newyork</City>
    </Drow>
    </DataToDb>
    </idRoot>";
echo "<hr />";
$send = $client->call("DataInsert",$tokenkey,$veri);
var_dump($send);
?>
```

The result:

```
Result

    Array
    (
        [AuthenticateResult] => 92528146-183B-4651-B852-6A1C97F1E908
    )

92528146-183B-4651-B852-6A1C97F1E908 //This means we connect the webservice and we got "token"
bool(false) //This means there is an error in data
```

Comment: WDSL here -> http://www.posta-tr.com/MassDataAccepter/MassDataAccepter.asmx?wsdl

Comment: As you can see i know where is the WDSL. My prolem is not that! Did you read my question?

Comment: DataInsert(token,data) expects 2 values, just like you do Authenticate(user,pass).  Why are you sending an array?

Comment: bu adam da cok artiz ama doğru demiş, oraya dizi vermemelisiniz, 2 parametre istiyor, ve 1 parametreyi boş gonderdiğiniz için webservice tarafında hataya sebep oluyor. sizden gelen bilgileri kontrol etmedikleri için direk .NET hatası dönüyor size.

Comment: Hmm, that also made me interested, I think he made XML file into array. does he have to directly insert XML string, and what's the second parameter?

Comment: Probably token returns from Authenticate() method, you need to use it as first parameter in DataInsert() method. Selamlar.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a .NET error, you cannot solve it on php side. but maybe a missing parameter.

For example :
if my function as

public void DataInsert(string test1,string s)

if s passed as null .net will throw an error as  "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: s" }"

http://www.posta-tr.com/MassDataAccepter/MassDataAccepter.asmx?op=DataInsert

```
 <DataInsert xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <Token>string</Token>
      <Data>string</Data>
    </DataInsert>
```

i think Data or Token is null, you passed only 1 parameter, and now Data is  null,
try send 2 parameter, first is Token and Second is Data.

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient("http://www.posta-tr.com/MassDataAccepter/MassDataAccepter.asmx?wsdl");
$connect = $client->Authenticate("accountname", "password");

$data = "<idRoot>
            <DataToDb>
            <Drow>
            <FName>George</FName>
            <LName>Houston</LName>
            <Email>gerorge@emailprovider.com</Email>
            <InvitedBy>Mary J</InvitedBy>
            <Job>Architect</Job>
            <City>Newyork</City>
            </Drow>
            </DataToDb>
            </idRoot>";

$send = $client->DataInsert($connect->AuthenticateResult,$data);
var_dump($send);

?>
```

Selamlar (:

Comment: Hi,Here you can see the .net (?) code of my webservice provider. How can i use this as php code?

Comment: i added an example you can try.

Comment: I tried but no change! Here the result:
object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["DataInsertResult"]=> string(51) "Hata : DI - Value cannot be null. Parameter name: s" }

Comment: change code as  "$send = $client->DataInsert($connect->AuthenticateResult,$data);    "

and var_dump($connect); what is the connect data ? you must get Token data first.

Comment: $connect dump:

object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["AuthenticateResult"]=> string(1) "0" }

$send dump (as $send = $client->DataInsert($connect->AuthenticateResult,$data); )

object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["DataInsertResult"]=> string(51) "Hata : DI - Value cannot be null. Parameter name: s" }

Comment: yes result look like as an auth problem. 

["AuthenticateResult"]=> string(1) "0"

Comment: use  $send = $client->call("DataInsert",array($tokenkey,$veri));
instead of 
$send = $client->call("DataInsert",$tokenkey,$veri);

Answer (score 0):

I think the params passed to DataInsert is incorrect, it should be like this:

```
/* Get token key here */
$token = $tokenKey;

$data = array(
  "idRoot" => array (
      "DataToDb" => array(
          "Drow" => array (
              "FName" => "George",
              "LName" => "Houston",
              "Email" => "gerorge@emailprovider.com",
              "InvitedBy" => "Mary J",
              "Job" => "Architect",
              "City" => "Newyork",
          )
      )
  )
);

$params = array(
  'Data' => $data,
  'Token' => $token
);

$client = new SoapClient( /* wsdl */ );
$response = $client->DataInsert($params);
```